# Excel 64-bit and comdlg32.dll custom colours

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to adapt the code in either [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153929)  or [here](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Colors.aspx) to open the custom colour palette in Excel 2010 64-bit but cannot get it to work. Code on both sites work fine in Excel 2003

One attempt

```
 Option Explicit

 Private Type CHOOSECOLOR
 lStructSize As Long
 hwndOwner As Long
 hInstance As Long
 rgbResult As Long
 lpCustColors As String
 flags As Long
 lCustData As Long
 lpfnHook As Long
 lpTemplateName As String
 End Type

 Private Declare PtrSafe Function ChooseColorAPI Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias _
 "ChooseColorA" (pChoosecolor As CHOOSECOLOR) As Long

 Dim CustomColors() As Byte

 Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim cc As CHOOSECOLOR
   Dim Custcolor(16) As Long
   Dim lReturn As Long
   cc.lStructSize = Len(cc)
   cc.hwndOwner = Application.Hwnd
   cc.hInstance = 0
   cc.lpCustColors = StrConv(CustomColors, vbUnicode)
   cc.flags = 0
   lReturn = ChooseColorAPI(cc)
   If lReturn <> 0 Then
       Application.Caption = "RGB Value User Chose: " & Str$(cc.rgbResult)
       Application.BackColor = cc.rgbResult            ' Visual Basic only ****
       Application.Section(0).BackColor = cc.rgbResult ' Access only **********
       CustomColors = StrConv(cc.lpCustColors, vbFromUnicode)
   Else
       MsgBox "User chose the Cancel Button"
   End If
   End Sub

   Private Sub Form_Load()
   ReDim CustomColors(0 To 16 * 4 - 1) As Byte
   Dim i As Integer

   For i = LBound(CustomColors) To UBound(CustomColors)
       CustomColors(i) = 0
   Next i
   End Sub
```

This runs ok but doesn't show the dialog. I've also tried changing some LONG types to LONGPTR with no success. Does anyone know how to get this working on a 64-bit machine; or if it's even possible? Perhaps there's a new library?

Thanks

**Edit:** Slight rewording with offer of bounty...
How do I access and use this custom colour chooser (image below) in Excel 2010 64-bit (MUST work on 64-bit!) to set cells in Excel 2010 with the colour chosen and store the colour? The image is taken from Excel 2010 64-bit by selecting fill button>more colors>Custom

[Valid XHTML http://img851.imageshack.us/img851/2057/unlednvn.png](http://img851.imageshack.us/img851/2057/unlednvn.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things I would try. First, replace every use of `Long` with `LongPtr`.

```
Private Type CHOOSECOLOR
    lStructSize As LongPtr
    hwndOwner As LongPtr
    hInstance As LongPtr
    rgbResult As LongPtr
    lpCustColors As String
    flags As LongPtr
    lCustData As LongPtr
    lpfnHook As LongPtr
    lpTemplateName As String
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function ChooseColorAPI Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias _
    "ChooseColorA" (pChoosecolor As CHOOSECOLOR) As LongPtr
```

Second, replace the use of `Len` with `LenB`.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim cc As CHOOSECOLOR
    Dim Custcolor(16) As LongPtr
    Dim lReturn As LongPtr

    cc.lStructSize = LenB(cc)
    cc.hwndOwner = Application.Hwnd
    cc.hInstance = 0
    cc.lpCustColors = StrConv(CustomColors, vbUnicode)
    cc.flags = 0
    lReturn = ChooseColorAPI(cc)

    If lReturn <> 0 Then
       Application.Caption = "RGB Value User Chose: " & Str$(cc.rgbResult)
       Application.BackColor = cc.rgbResult            ' Visual Basic only ****
       Application.Section(0).BackColor = cc.rgbResult ' Access only **********
       CustomColors = StrConv(cc.lpCustColors, vbFromUnicode)
    Else
       MsgBox "User chose the Cancel Button"

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ReDim CustomColors(0 To 16 * 4 - 1) As Byte
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = LBound(CustomColors) To UBound(CustomColors)
       CustomColors(i) = 0
    Next i
End Sub
```

**More Info**

[LongPtr Data Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251378.aspx)

[LenB Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/len-lenb-HP005209154.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK 32-bit dll's cannot be used by a 64-bit application.
Use comdlg64.dll instead (if there is such a dll).

Using google reveals that there a host of viruses floating around on the net by that name.
So if `comdlg64.dll` is not on your machine **don't download it** from the net!
*(Unless you want to experience zombieness).*

Comment: 32-bit dll's can be used as long as the datatypes are handled correctly. Usually it just means declaring as 'PtrSafe' but sometimes the datatypes need changed such as LongLong, LongPtr etc. All of the previous 32-bit dlls I've used work fine in 64-bit except "comdlg32.dll"? See [Link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/HV080353309.aspx)