# Cannot get the Color Picker to work in Excel 2010 64 Bit

Tags: vba, excel, 64-bit, color-picker

Hello I am struggling to get VBA code updated for Excel 2010 64 Bit. I have checked all over, including an informative post here on StackOverflow: [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724396/excel-64-bit-and-comdlg32-dll-custom-colours)
I do understand i have to Declare PtrSafe and create LongPtr and LongLong where applicable, but i get a "Compile Error. Type Mismatch"  on the ".rgbResult" portion of the Private Function Code. Any any and all help would be greatly appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
     #If Win64 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function ChooseColor Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "ChooseColorA" (pChoosecolor As ChooseColor) As LongPtr
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
        Private Type ChooseColor
            lStructSize As LongPtr
            hwndOwner As LongPtr
            hInstance As LongPtr
            rgbResult As LongPtr
            lpCustColors As String
            flags As LongPtr
            lCustData As LongPtr
            lpfnHook As LongPtr
            lpTemplateName As String
            End Type
      #Else
       '{{{This Section of Code works ok so i have excluded it to save space as its the same as above without the ptr}}}}}
      #End If
#Else
        '{{{This Section of Code works ok so i have excluded it to save space}}}}}
#End If


#If VBA7 Then
     #If Win64 Then
            Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowColor Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "ShowColorA" (pShowColor As ShowColor) As LongPtr
                Dim ChooseColorStructure As ChooseColor
                Dim Custcolor(16) As LongPtr
                Dim lReturn As LongPtr

                                        On Error GoTo ErrEnd:
                ChooseColorStructure.lStructSize = LenB(ChooseColorStructure)
                ChooseColorStructure.hwndOwner = FindWindow("XLMAIN", Application.Caption)
                ChooseColorStructure.hInstance = 0
                ChooseColorStructure.lpCustColors = StrConv(Custcolor(16), vbUnicode)
                ChooseColorStructure.flags = 0
                If ChooseColor(ChooseColorStructure) <> 0 Then
                    ShowColor = ChooseColorStructure.rgbResult

                    Custcolor(16) = StrConv(ChooseColorStructure.lpCustColors, vbFromUnicode)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Else
                    ShowColor = -1
                End If
ErrEnd:
         End Function
    #Else
           '{{{This Section of Code works ok so i have excluded it to save space}}}}}
         #End If
#Else
             '{{{This Section of Code works ok so i have excluded it to save space}}}}}

            End Function
```

Comment: dunno if this would do much or not but the findwindow function im pretty sure needs to be declared with `As LongPtr` and you judt have it with `as Long`

Comment: Also, in the posted question, the choose color function was: `ChooseColorAPI` instead of yours: `ChooseColor`

Comment: Ahh i see that. OK i will make that update. IF you, or anyone, see anything else, I really appreciate that. I have been using a customers machine to test this so i cannot check it right now. Thanksssssss

Comment: Yeah on that other post, they were different. I tried to take as much from that one as possible, however my code was still quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   lStructSize As LongPtr
```

You are going overboard declaring the members LongPtr instead of Long.  LongPtr should only be used if the member is a *pointer* or *handle* type, lStructSize is not a pointer.  Same for several other members, including rgbResult.  It needs to look like this:

```
    Private Type ChooseColor
        lStructSize As Long
        hwndOwner As LongPtr
        hInstance As LongPtr
        rgbResult As Long
        lpCustColors As LongPtr
        flags As Long
        lCustData As LongPtr
        lpfnHook As LongPtr
        lpTemplateName As String
    End Type
```

Comment: does that mean longPtr Stands for Long `Pointer` then?

Comment: Yes, "Ptr" means Pointer.

Comment: Thanks, neither did I. I really need to learn this stuff fast, as more people adopt 64 bit. I feel like I'm falling behind here. (Will be testing this code on my customers machine tonight so i can get proper feedback) I really appreciate the help. (Then off to get a new 64 bit machine this weekend)

Comment: Thanks so much for both of your help.  I was able to get it working by removing the unnecessary Ptr's.  I also had to make sure my copy included  "BLen"  instead of Len.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After searching some more, I'm pretty sure the ChooseColor should actually be `as Long` instead of `as LongPtr`

I did a google search with quotes for the declaration: "`Private Declare PtrSafe Function ChooseColor Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "ChooseColorA" (pChoosecolor As ChooseColor) As LongPtr`"

and I only got 2 results: this question, and a post on some other site, but I couldn't read it as it was in french which I've been meaning to learn but haven't.

I did a search with: "`Private Declare PtrSafe Function ChooseColor Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "ChooseColorA" (pChoosecolor As ChooseColor) As Long`" and I got significantly more results with that, so I think it should be declared as a long instead of longPtr on that one. Even in 64 some still need to return longs instead of longPtr

### edit

this page: http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp?AllComments=True mentions chooseColor function in the comments, and they have it declared with `As Long` instead of longPtr there. just in case if you wanted a reference :)

Comment: OK for sure I am going to give that a try. Explanation makes sense. I am a relatively amateur VBA programmer, who rarely uses Functions, and this 64 bit is really throwing me for a loop

Comment: hah, no probs, I am too, but I was tossed in to a massive VBA project 2 months ago so it's fly or die right now for me XP I didn't even know  what a `longPtr` is, or that API calls like that existed in VBA. took a whole day to figure out how to close a windows explorer window using the `findwindow` and `sendmessage` and then i tested it on 64 bit machine, that was half a day figuring out what the hell to do with that one... thank god for the site i linked, it saved my bacon