# VBA Excel DLL - Error 48

Tags: vba, excel, dll

I've recently gotten a piece of VBA code that was made on a 2003 based Office edition and is 32 bit based. I only have 64 bit Office 2016, and I updated the code to below - yet when I run the macro I get a "Run-time Error - File Not Found "Swings4-2.dll". Even if I remove the file extension an error still pops up. The DLL file is located in the same directory as the XLS/XLSM file, and even if I quote the full directory of the file - it continues to give me an error.

```
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Swings Lib "Swings4-2.dll" (ByRef Par1 As Integer, ByRef Par2 As Integer, _
       ByRef Par3 As Single, ByRef Par4 As Single, ByRef Par5 As Single, ByRef Par6 As Single, _
       ByRef Par7 As Single, ByRef Par8 As Single, ByRef Par9 As Single, ByRef Par10 As Single, _
       ByRef Par11 As Single, ByRef Parl2 As Single, ByRef Parl3 As Single, ByRef Parl4 As Single)
#Else
    Private Declare Sub Swings Lib "Swings4-2.dll" (ByRef Par1 As Integer, ByRef Par2 As Integer, _
       ByRef Par3 As Single, ByRef Par4 As Single, ByRef Par5 As Single, ByRef Par6 As Single, _
       ByRef Par7 As Single, ByRef Par8 As Single, ByRef Par9 As Single, ByRef Par10 As Single, _
       ByRef Par11 As Single, ByRef Parl2 As Single, ByRef Parl3 As Single, ByRef Parl4 As Single)
#End If
```

Help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Open a command prompt with Administrator rights. Type "regsvr32 path\swings4-2.dll" (omit quotation marks, and replace path with the path to the dll file). If the dll gods are with us, this will fix things.

Comment: Not sure you can call a 32-bit dll from a 64-bit VBA runtime...

Comment: @Tim Williams My understanding is that you can. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724396/excel-64-bit-and-comdlg32-dll-custom-colours

Comment: I though that a 64-bit or "any CPU"-compiled dll was required?  Eg see http://www.cadsharp.com/blog/solidworks-macro-compatible-64-vba7/  and  https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-FF023966-A01D-4B64-8957-7C0F02BF8162-htm.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a nonstandard name for your dll.

> Occasionally, a DLL procedure has a name that is not a legal
>   identifier. It might have an invalid character such as a hyphen. When
>   this is the case, use the Alias keyword to specify the illegal
>   procedure name.

For more info please see [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716201(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: The procedure name is "swings". The DLL name has the hyphen.