# How to udpate the basColorPicker module in Access to 64 bit?

Tags: vba, ms-access, module, 64-bit

I saved a .mdb database to the current .accdb version in O365 and immediately got an error related to the basColorPicker module (see screenshot).

Any idea on how to go by fixing it?

I tried to update the Long to LongPtr, but error remains highliting the word Funtion in:

```
Private Declare Function ChooseColor Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "ChooseColorA" _
  (pChoosecolor As COLORSTRUC) As LongPtr
```

Comment: Have you already made `COLORSTRUC` 64-bit compatible?  You may find [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5810803/77335)  useful.

Comment: Yes thank you HansUp - I've updated almost everything using the post you suggested except one word: PtrSafe in the declaration. The error is gone now. Iw ill test it and report later.